# Django says TemplateNotFound even if the template is there

Tags: python, django

Can someone help me in figuring out where I went wrong?

Project URLs

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('trips/',include('trips.urls')),
    path('customers/',include('customers.urls')),
    path('drivers/',include('drivers.urls')),
    path('vehicles/',include('vehicles.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

App URLs

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.customers, name='customers'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.customer_details, name='customer_details'),
]
```

App View

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import *

# Create your views here.
def customers(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all().order_by('id')
    return render(request, "customers.html", {'customers': customers, 'custactive': "active"})

def customer_details(request, pk):
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
    return render(request, "/customer_details.html", {'customer': customer})
```

How I'm calling the page

```
<td><a href="{% url 'customer_details' pk=customer.pk %}">{{customer.name}}</a></td>
```

**I'm hoping to render the template at localhost/customers/id**

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll need to share where the template is located in your project, and what the value for ```TEMPLATES``` is in your settings.py file. 

If you use the default template backend and your customer_details.html file is inside a templates folder, I think referencing the template without the slash, so ```return render(request, "customer_details.html", {'customer': customer})``` should work.

Comment: You can specify directory to look for using this setting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#dirs

Answer (score 0):

In your function customer_details you return :

```
return render(request, "/customer_details.html", {'customer': customer})
```

You have to return "customer_details.html" without the / :

```
return render(request, "customer_details.html", {'customer': customer})
```